# Why is Docker limiting my container's CPU usage to 100% on Raspberry

Tags: performance, docker, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3

I'm running the latest docker version on Raspbian on my RaspberryPi 3.

I have a program that takes pictures with the camera, compresses them and sends them over the network.

When I run the program outside of docker I can see using top that it's constantly consuming around 130% CPU (of 4cores x 100% of the raspberry). The constant compression is the CPU intensive part of the program but it manages to compress around 32 fps.

When I run the exact same program in a docker container I can see in top that it is only using 100% cpu (still distributed among the cores). Here the program is only able to compress at around 23 fps.

I tried passing the --cpus flag but it returned an error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: NanoCPUs can not be set, as your kernel does not support CPU cfs period/quota or the cgroup is not mounted.`

Note: I have done many tests and networking is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem.

When creating the image via the Dockerfile it downloaded the different versions of the libraries I used in the code. So technically it was running different code from what was running on the host and it was not a docker issue.